# Use examples to identify the need of join dependency

Tags: database-theory, databases

> Use examples to identify the need of join dependency.

This is what I have gathered from different website's.

1. SQL joins are used to combine rows from two or more tables.
2. A **Join Dependency** (**JD**) over a relation schema R is a statement of the form |><|[schema(R1), schema(R2), …, schema(Rn)], where **R** = {R1, R2, …, Rn} is a database schema such that schema(**R**)=schema(R).
3. The general lossless decomposition constraint, involving any number of projections, is also known as a join dependency.

Comment: Who posed this problem? What does "need" mean here? What have you tried towards creating an example?

Comment: need->   to require something because they are essential or very important, not just because you would like to have them.

Comment: What is the meaning of the symbol, |><| ?

Comment: @rajeshsingh That sentence defines the meaning of $\bowtie$.

Comment: @Gilles Can you elaborate the meaning ?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we had a relation $R(A,B,C)$ and we decomposed it into two relations $S_1(A,B)$ and $S_2(B,C)$. Then we'd like the decomposition to have the property that the natural join of the projected relations $\Pi_{A,B}(R)$ and $\Pi_{B,C}(R)$ would produce $R$. Essentially, we'd like to be able to retrieve the original $R$ from the two relations in decomposition $S_1, S_2$, which is exactly what the join dependency in your question requires.

This won't always happen. Suppose we had this instance of $R$:
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
A & B & C \\
1 & 2 & 3\\
2 & 2 & 4
\end{array}$$
Then projecting $R$ onto $S_1(A,B)$ and $S_2(B,C)$ would give us, respectively
$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
A & B &\qquad\qquad & B & C\\
1 & 2 & & 2 & 3\\
2 & 2 & & 2 & 4
\end{array}$$
and so in the join $S_1\bowtie S_2$ we'd have
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
A & B & C\\
1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & 2 & 4\\
2 & 2 & 3\\
2 & 2 & 4
\end{array}$$
Notice that the join contains the original tuples $(1,2,3),(2,2,4)$ of $R$, but we've introduced two spurious tuples in the join, $(1,2,4),(2,2,3)$, which were not in the original relation $R$. This is a situation we certainly don't want to have, which is why any such decomposition should satisfy the join dependency.